# wampserver 2.5 mysql data location not changing

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I have recently upgraded to Wampserver 2.5 64bit - on a Windows 7 64 bit computer.
I have uninstalled the previous version 2.2 prior to installaion.

I am trying to change the data location for the mysql files -
I have edited mysql 'my.ini' and set datadir="d:/mysql/data" 
(where the previous version databases were located.)

I have restarted all services but it doesn't seem to be using the correct data location -

When I log into 'localhost' using sqlYog it shows me the databases in the default location 
c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data

Answer (score 1):

There was a small bug in the 2.5 64bit release.

Edit your my.ini and change the section name from [wampmysqld] to [wampmysqld64]

This section name in the ini file must match the service name used by the MySQL server, and they changed the service name to wampmysqld64 and forgot to change the my.ini file accordingly.

Once this is done MySQL should see your changed setting in my.ini

**BIG NOTE**

Also you cannot just point the new MySQL version at the old files and expect it to work. I cannot remember the version of MySQL that came with WAMPServer 2.2 but the databases created with it are almost definitely not going to be compatible with MySQL5.6.

You had better read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading.html